# Iterating Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I use Angular Material `mat-table` and as far as I see, it has a special notation for loop properties like `*matCellDef` as shown on this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yorydvmqlpv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html). In order to remove the unnecessary part, I am trying to iterate records and build table dynamically. I tried to iterate using `<div let element of elements>...</div>` but failed. So, may it be possible using a special syntax?

Here is the part I have tried to iterate:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: MatTable automatically binds to arrays. Just set column names and field property names. Here a primer https://dev.to/jwp/angular-material-table-in-20-minutes-15f4

Comment: @JohnPeters Thanks a alot, it seesm to be useful. But in the first part, I see that the column names are not gathered from the data source and given statically. Why I want to make this is that, I want to create a base list component and do not set the column names statically. Is that possible?

Comment: Mat-Table uses both DisplayedColumns and DisplayedHeaders.  Both are arrays and both can be passed in by any dynamic component at run time.   Just grab the instance of MatTable and do this.  myMatTable.displayedColumns=["col1","col2"] and myMatTable.displayedHeaders = ["Dynamic Header 1", "Dynamic Header2"]

Comment: Thanks for help. What about `matColumnDef`? DO I have to set `defxxx` properties in Material Table (mat*table)? And what is the difference between `matColumnDef` and `[matColumnDef]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a reusable matTable view component like this:

We can see that columnHeaders is an array.

```
<ng-container 
  *ngFor="let colName of columnHeaders; let i = index" 
      matColumnDef="{{ displayedColumns[i] }}"
 >
```

The header values

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
  <span>
    {{ colName }}
  </span>
</th>
```

Actual row values using the displayedCoumns array.

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
 <span>
   {{ row[displayedColumns[i]] }}
 </span>
</td>
```

And the data Binding

```
<table
     [id]="tableId"
     matSort
     mat-table
     [(dataSource)]="dataSource"    
  >...
```

This allows one to inject the dataSource which is an array of anything, as well as an array of columnheaders and dsiplaycolumns like this:

To reuse the matTable component shown above, we can inject the columnHeaders, displayedColumns and the dataSource like this code shows.

```
@ViewChild(ParentComponent) matTable:ParentComponent
displayedColumns = ["id", "firstName", "lastName", "updated", "actions"];
columnHeaders = ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Last Updated", "Actions"];

 private setTableColumns() {
      if (this.people.length > 0) {
         this.matTable.displayedColumns = this.displayedColumns;
         this.matTable.columnHeaders = this.columnHeaders;
         this.matTable.dataSource = this.myArray;
      }
   }
```

Or like this in html assuming that app-material-table is a reusable view showing having the bindings shown above.

```
<app-material-table
   [dataSoure]="myArray"
   [columnHeaders]="columnHeaders"
   [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns"     
</app-material-table>
```

Note: Whenever I see something like MatTable I instantly think about creating a more simplified reusable view that abstracts the knowledge of using it to something easier as shown above.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Regarding to your Note, do you mean something like [this](https://medium.com/@danilrabizo/reusable-angular-material-table-ac0b02162293) example? I followed it and seems to ok. Any comment on it (it also has [GitHub](https://github.com/dnlrbz/angular-material/blob/master/src/app/orders-table/orders.component.ts) page).

Comment: Thanks for the post I'm interested in seeing that solution too.

Comment: In this case you suggest me to use the approach that I gave in my previous comment. Is there any changes on that approach that you suggest?